# Cisco Small Business SG 102-24 switch

Tags: networking, switch

Does anyone know what the limit is with regards to expansion on the Cisco Small Business SG 102-24 switch? How many of these can be connected together at one time? I have a network that will require at lease 3 X 24 port switches. Should this switch work in that environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just planning on connecting them together with the front ports, then you can easily connect 3 of them together.  There are other limits like spanning tree, etc. but that comes in to play more above 6.